# Get product attribute by attribute group code in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Please help.
I want get attribute by [attribute_group_code]. Please help me. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$product = $this->getProduct();
$attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
$groupCollection = $this->groupCollectionFactory->create()
    ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
    ->setSortOrder()
    ->load();
foreach ($groupCollection as $group) :            
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();            
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($group->getData());
    echo "</pre>";  
    ?>
    Return :
        Array
        (
            [attribute_group_id] => 21
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [attribute_group_name] => Operate
            [sort_order] => 3
            [default_id] => 0
            [attribute_group_code] => operate
            [tab_group_code] => 
        )

    // Get attribute value , label
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I just want to get these attribute groups (operate) values based on ['attribute_group_code']. Because when creating the attribute group in admin, I will not know the id of the attribute group, so I only rely on the attribute_group_code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the product attributes within a specific attribute group by passing the attribute group id to `$product->getAttributes($groupId)`

So in your `foreach ($groupCollection as $group)` you can do the following:

```
if ($group->getAttributeGroupCode() == 'your_attribute_code') {
    $groupId = $group->getAttributeGroupId();
} else {
    continue; //it's the wrong group so you can continue with the next
}
```

With this you get `$groupId` and you can get your product attributes of the group with:
`$product->getAttributes($groupId)`

Comment: Thanks for your support